# Как поменять IP tor browser в python?

Tags: python, requests, tor

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не меняется IP tor browser при парсинге. Решил проверить как выглядит мой IP в запросах и нашел такую функцию.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import socks
import socket
from time import sleep

def checkIP():
    ip = requests.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org').content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ip, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find('body').text)


socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
i = 0
while i <=100:
  i += 1
  checkIP()
  sleep(2)
```

Конечно IP меняется, но только один раз. Как сделать чтоб смена IP происходила каждые пару минут, или при каких-то ошибок, к примеру ошибка при запросе сайта, который банит IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно изменить файл `/etc/tor/torrc` или `path/to/your/torbrowser/Data/Tor/torrc`, внеся следующее значение:

```
MaxCircuitDirtiness NUM
```

Где `NUM` - максимальное время жизни соединения в секундах (то есть и `IP` тоже).

Источник: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216653/how-to-let-tor-change-ip-automatically).

Comment: @Евгений подключение можно создать, если будет к чему подключаться (например, `HTTP`/`HTTPS`/`SOCKS` прокси).

Comment: Рад, что помогло, и буду рад еще больше, если примете ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Запуск сокс прокси с помощью библиотеки stem

```
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

[Источник](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html)